# PhpStorm/WebStorm terminal shows old NPM version

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, webstorm

I am on `Windows 10 x64` running `PhpStorm 2018.3`.  I have updated NodeJS to 10.14.1 which includes NPM 6.4.1.

The Windows command line tool shows the correct versions
[image]

PhpStorm settings show the correct versions
[image]

The problem I have is that the PhpStorm terminal still shows NPM 3.10.10 although it shows the correct Node version.

[image]

I have tried:

- Restarting PhpStorm
- Restarting the computer
- Uninstalling and re-installing Node, then restarting the computer

This causes trouble because the version of NPM running in my IDE terminal cannot see the globally installed packages.

Global packages from Windows command line

[image]

Global packages from PhpStorm terminal

[image]

How do I get to the bottom of this?

#### Update

Running `where npm` from the PhpStorm terminal shows that a local dependency has installed the older NPM version

[image]

[image]

Is it expected for a locally installed NPM to make it impossible for the terminal to see my global packages?

#### Update 2

When I run the Windows command line tool from within the project folder, everything works as expected, unlike the PhpStorm terminal. The right version is seen, global packages are seen, and the `where` command cannot see the local NPM installed in *node_modules*

[image]

#### Resolution

Thanks to Lena for the solution. Turns out that with `PhpStorm 2018.3`, [a new enabled-by-default setting](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33571) adds the binaries in the project's local `./node_modules/.bin` to `$PATH`, so the terminal would see the locally installed NPM version instead of the global one.  To resolve the issue I went to `Settings > Tools > Terminal` and unchecked this option:

> Add node_modules/.bin from the project root to %PATH%

If anyone involved is reading this, I would suggest allowing the user to add a blacklist of binaries that should not be added when this option is checked.

Comment: Do you have any other instance of NPM installed? Through `where`, you could search for it

Comment: @NicoHaase what is the actual command please? I'm on Windows.  `npm where` doesn't match any command

Comment: @BeetleJuice No, `where npm`

Comment: @LazyOne thanks that showed that a local package in the project has installed npm 3.10.  If I uninstall that package, the right version starts showing up but I get missing dependency errors.  I'll add the info to the OP.  Is a locally installed npm version supposed to block the terminal from seeing global packages?

Comment: hmm... does the issue persist if you open built-in terminal in different folder? Create a new empty project, without local npm installed, open terminal in it - what is the result? Npm scripts, when running, add local npm modules binaries to `$PATH`, but I'm not sure it's the problem

Comment: @lena an empty project shows the right `npm` version.  Also as I noted in my update to the OP, the correct `npm` version is shown if I run `npm uninstall` on the dependency that had a local copy of NPM.

Comment: ok. Now open your system cmd console in your project folder - what is the result? i suspect that it will be the same as in built-in terminal

Comment: @lena Good thought.  Surprisingly though, the windows cmd line shows the correct version even when I'm in the project folder! The Windows tool can also see the globally installed packages even from the project folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by **Add 'node_modules/.bin' from the project root to $PATH** (**Settings | Tools | Terminal**) - as you have `npm` binary in `node_modules/.bin`, it's also added to `%PATH%` and thus used when running `npm` in terminal. Disabling this option should solve the issue

Comment: Thanks Lena. Do you know whether this is a new setting? Or set as default-enabled on recent versions of the IDE? I don't remember ever touching that one, and I didn't have this problem a few months ago.

Comment: it's a new option, added in 2018.3 at users' requests - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33571

Comment: Actually I just checked.  The machine with the problem was recently upgraded to `PhpStorm 2018.3`; my other machine still has `2018.2.5` and on the older version, the setting in question does not exist.

Comment: Might make sense to add a blacklist of binaries that should not be added to %PATH% when this option is checked. This way users can use the option but not overwrite global binaries if they don't want to.

Comment: THis doesn't work anymore 2024... disabling the option does not work