# Node version is different in PhpStorm and Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, phpstorm, ubuntu-22.04

After updating node my PhpStorm terminal is still showing the older version while my Ubuntu terminal is showing the updated version.

I came across this issue when running `npm start` and `npm install` were both failing due to incompatible node version.

After running `which node` on both terminals I get these results:

- PhpStorm: `/bin/node`
- Ubuntu: `/usr/local/bin/node`

Trying the top answer to this question didn't work for me:
[PhpStorm/WebStorm terminal shows old NPM version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53559809/phpstorm-webstorm-terminal-shows-old-npm-version)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because JetBrains IDEs can alter your `$PATH` env var when it starts a terminal. Check your settings in your **Settings | Tools | Terminal** section. There are a few settings that may need to be altered. Look for anything that mentions `$PATH`:

**`Add default project PHP interpreter to $PATH`** - Unless you are purposefully maintaining separate php versions for different projects, you can safely uncheck this. If your PHP interpreter is set to `/bin` or `/usr/bin` it could be ***prepending*** that to your `$PATH` and thus overriding `/usr/local/bin` for your `node` and `npm` binaries. If you want to purposefully use a separate php version for a project, I would recommend installing it in a separate directory so as not to conflict with other binaries.

**`Add 'node_modules/.bin' from the project root to $PATH`** - If you have  npm installed in your `node_modules/.bin`, then  you may want to use it rather than your global npm. However, according to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33571, this setting will now ***append*** `node_modules/.bin` to your `$PATH` and therefore your global npm will be used. This is probably the desired behavior, but if you do want to use the version from `node_modules/.bin`, then you'll need  to either call it directly (ie. `node_modules/.bin/npm start`) or add it to your `$PATH` manually in `~/.bashrc`.

(add `export PATH="path/to/project/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"` to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file, then restart your terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc`)